# How to simplify multiple or conditions in an if statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

So I wanted to write this:

```
if x % 2 == 0 or x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0 or x % 7 == 0:
```

But this way:

```
if x % (2 or 3 or 5 or 7) == 0:
```

How should I write it in a proper way?

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​`if any(x % i for i in [2, 3, 5, 7]):` - Now who can help me find the dupe target?

Comment: @KevinGuan Actually: `if any(not x%i for i in (2,3,5,7))` or `if not all(x%i for i in (2,3,5,7))`.

Comment: @Bakuriu: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Ah, correct. Or just `if any(x % i == 0 for i in [2, 3, 5, 7]):` like OP's code.

Comment: I'm astonished by the pace how quickly you answered my question. Thank you guys!

Comment: I've edited the title to make this question searchable. I know it was asked plently of time but trying the obvious things like "python multiple or" etc doesn't lead to any good fit.

Answer (score 8):

`or` is a boolean operator. It calls `bool` over the left argument and see if the result is `True` and if it is it returns the left argument, otherwise it returns the right argument, so you cannot do `x % (1 or 2 or 3)` because this evaluates to just `x % 1` since `1 or 2 or 3 == 1`:

```
>>> True or False
True
>>> False or True
True
>>> False or False
False
>>> 1 or False   # all numbers != 0 are "true"
1
>>> bool(1)
True
>>> 1 or 2 or 3   #(1 or 2) or 3 == 1 or 3 == 1
1
```

Whenever you have multiple conditions you can try to reduce them using [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) or [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all).

We have that `any([a,b,c,d])` is equivalent to `a or b or c or d` while `all([a,b,c,d])` is equivalent to `a and b and c and d` **except** that they always return `True` or `False`.

So for example:

```
if any(x%i == 0 for i in (2,3,5,7)):
```

Equivalently (since `0` if the only false number the `== 0` is equivalent to `not`):

```
if any(not x%i for i in (2,3,5,7)):
```

Equivalently:

```
if not all(x%i for i in (2,3,5,7))
```

Keep in mind that (de Morgan law: `not a or not b == not (a and b)`):

```
any(not p for p in some_list) == not all(p for p in some_list)
```

Note that using a generator expression makes `any` and `all` short-circuit so not all conditions are evaluated. See the difference between:

```
>>> any(1/x for x in (1,0))
True
>>> 1 or 1/0
1
```

And:

```
>>> any([1/x for x in (1,0)])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
>>> 1/0 or 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

In the last example the `1/0` is evaluated *before* calling `any`.